# Kotlin Compose, Align items in row

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I'm using the brand new Kotlin `Compose` for my view, I have a row with 2 items, how can I make them `center-vertical`-like?

```
    Row(
            modifier = Spacing(20.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = "Hello $name!")
        Spacing(10.dp)
        Padding(padding = 25.dp) {
            Button(text = "Click", onClick = { /*do something*/ })

        }
    }
```

[image]

Note that without padding they are not aligned too.

Comment: You want to align them screen center-vertical?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There's `verticalAlignment` argument in [Row](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#row). You can also configure an item alignment individually using [align](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#align) modifier which overrides the row's `verticalAlignment`. For example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun RowAlignmentExample() {
    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        SizeTile(14)
        SizeTile(18)
        SizeTile(22)
        SizeTile(26)
        SizeTile(10, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Top))
        SizeTile(10, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Bottom))
    }
}

@Composable
fun SizeTile(fontSize: Int, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = fontSize.toString(),
        fontSize = fontSize.sp,
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(2.dp)
            .background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
            .padding(2.dp)
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

You can use the **`verticalAlignment`** parameter in the `Row`.
Something like:

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    Text(text = "Hello!")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
    Button(onClick = { /*do something*/ },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(25.dp)) {
        Text(text = "Click")
    }
}
```

[image]

You can also use the [`align`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#align) modifier defined in the `RowScope` in each composable in the `Row`.
Pls note that:

> Align the element vertically within the `Row`. This alignment **will have priority** over the `Row`'s `verticalAlignment` parameter.

```
Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    // The child with no align modifier is positioned by default so that is in the middle of
    // the vertical axis.
    Box(Modifier.size(80.dp, 40.dp).background(Teal200))

    // Gravity.Top, the child will be positioned so that its top edge is aligned to the top
    // of the vertical axis.
    Box(Modifier.size(80.dp, 40.dp).align(Alignment.Top).background(Color.Red))

    // Gravity.Center, the child will be positioned so that its center is in the middle of
    // the vertical axis.
    Box(Modifier.size(80.dp, 40.dp).align(Alignment.CenterVertically).background(Color.Yellow))

    // Gravity.Bottom, the child will be positioned so that its bottom edge is aligned to the
    // bottom of the vertical axis.
    Box(Modifier.size(80.dp, 40.dp).align(Alignment.Bottom).background(Color.Green))

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

On compose version 1.0, this is a solution...

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    Text(text = "Hello Android!",
        modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 10.dp))
    Button(text = { Text("Click") },
        onClick = { /*do something*/ },
        modifier = Modifier.padding(25.dp)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Align` composable

```
Align(Alignment.TopCenter) { //You can change the alignment to fit your needs.
    Row(modifier = Spacing(20.dp)) {
        Text(text = "Hello $name!")
        Spacing(10.dp)
        Padding(padding = 25.dp) {
            Button(text = "Click", onClick = { /*do something*/ })
        }
    }
}
```

The code above should align the entire row, but you will need to wrap every component individually if you want them to be aligned center in regards to the `row.`

Answer (score 0):

In **1.0.1** you use **verticalArrangement** like this:

```
Row(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(70.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
) {
    ...
}
```